# Multiple subquery join in View with group by returns duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-view

I have created a view using subquery but I want this view to return few mendatory column which cant be added in group by subquery, so I have to create one more select statement and join with other group by subquery

I am come up with following query, 
But problem I am facing is if group by seller has 28 rows it returns 28 duplicate rows, also I want whole query to order by TotalOrderItem.

```
Alter VIEW [dbo].[SellersPerformance] AS


Select 
    RequiredColumns.Id as Id,
    aggrgateDT.SellerId as SellerId,
    aggrgateDT.TenantId as TenantId,
    aggrgateDT.Active as Active,
    aggrgateDT.TotalOrderedItem as TotalOrderItem,
    aggrgateDT.MoveToPurchase as MoveToPurchase,
    aggrgateDT.GoodPurchase as GoodPurchase,
     RequiredColumns.Created as Created,
    RequiredColumns.Modified as Modified,
    RequiredColumns.CreatorId as CreatorId,
    RequiredColumns.ModifierId as ModifierId


 From
 (
(Select 
sellerId, p.TenantId, p.Active, count(*) as TotalOrderedItem, 
   count(*) - count(o.Id) as MoveToPurchase,
       count(o.Id) as GoodPurchase,
  count(case when o.ApplicationStatus = 'Perfect' then 1 end) as Perfect,
     count(case when o.ApplicationStatus = 'R-Perfect' then 1 end) as R_Perfect

  FROM [dbo].[AmazonOrderPurchaseInfo] p
  left join [dbo].[AmazonOrder] o
  on p.AmazonOrderId = o.Id
    AND p.Id = o.[AmazonOrderPurchaseInfoId]
  group by SellerId, p.TenantId, p.Active
 order by TotalOrderedItem offset 0 rows
) aggrgateDT

 Left outer Join (
 SELECT 
       NEWID() Id,
       purchase.Created     AS Created,
       purchase.Modified    AS Modified,
       purchase.CreatorId   AS CreatorId,
       purchase.ModifierId  AS ModifierId,
       purchase.SellerId      As SellerId

       From dbo.AmazonOrderPurchaseInfo purchase

 ) RequiredColumns ON aggrgateDT.SellerId = RequiredColumns.SellerId

 )

GO
```

Comment: how about select distinct?

Comment: @metal tried distinct its not working

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, particularly with a simplified example.

Answer (score -1):

You may try `Group by` for this.

```
Alter VIEW [dbo].[SellersPerformance] AS

select res.Id, res.SellerId, res.TenandId, res.Active, res.TotalOrderItem, res.MovetoPurchase, res.GoodPurchase, res.Created, res.Modified, res.CreatorId, res.ModifierId
from

(

Select 
    RequiredColumns.Id as Id,
    aggrgateDT.SellerId as SellerId,
    aggrgateDT.TenantId as TenantId,
    aggrgateDT.Active as Active,
    aggrgateDT.TotalOrderedItem as TotalOrderItem,
    aggrgateDT.MoveToPurchase as MoveToPurchase,
    aggrgateDT.GoodPurchase as GoodPurchase,
     RequiredColumns.Created as Created,
    RequiredColumns.Modified as Modified,
    RequiredColumns.CreatorId as CreatorId,
    RequiredColumns.ModifierId as ModifierId


 From
 (
(Select 
sellerId, p.TenantId, p.Active, count(*) as TotalOrderedItem, 
   count(*) - count(o.Id) as MoveToPurchase,
       count(o.Id) as GoodPurchase,
  count(case when o.ApplicationStatus = 'Perfect' then 1 end) as Perfect,
     count(case when o.ApplicationStatus = 'R-Perfect' then 1 end) as R_Perfect

  FROM [dbo].[AmazonOrderPurchaseInfo] p
  left join [dbo].[AmazonOrder] o
  on p.AmazonOrderId = o.Id
    AND p.Id = o.[AmazonOrderPurchaseInfoId]
  group by SellerId, p.TenantId, p.Active
 order by TotalOrderedItem offset 0 rows
) aggrgateDT

 Left outer Join (
 SELECT 
       NEWID() Id,
       purchase.Created     AS Created,
       purchase.Modified    AS Modified,
       purchase.CreatorId   AS CreatorId,
       purchase.ModifierId  AS ModifierId,
       purchase.SellerId      As SellerId

       From dbo.AmazonOrderPurchaseInfo purchase

 ) RequiredColumns ON aggrgateDT.SellerId = RequiredColumns.SellerId

) as res
 group by  res.Id, res.SellerId, res.TenandId, res.Active, res.TotalOrderItem, res.MovetoPurchase, res.GoodPurchase, res.Created, res.Modified, res.CreatorId, res.ModifierId

 )

GO
```

Here if `Id, Created, Modified, CreatorId, ModifierId` columns will have same id then you may get your expected result.